# "&" character in facebook sharer url

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, replace, facebook-sharer

My site has urls like

```
$shareurl = http://www.mysite.com/?view=main&title=here-is-some-title
```

So if i put this url in facebook and twitter sharer links appear like below

**facebook sharer url:**

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=MY_APP_ID&link=<?php echo $shareurl;?>&picture=Picture.jpg&name=this is name&caption=this is caption&description=this is despcription.&redirect_uri=<?php echo APP_BASE_URL; ?>""> Share on Facebook </a>
```

`&` character into `$sharerurl` splits the facebook sharer url. The situation is same in Twitter.
How can i avoid from this condition by simplest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this code you should be fine:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=MY_APP_ID&link=<?php echo urlencode($shareurl);?>&picture=Picture.jpg&name=this is name&caption=this is caption&description=this is despcription.&redirect_uri=<?php echo APP_BASE_URL; ?>""> Share on Facebook </a>
```

It turns the `&`s in the URL into `%26`, which Facebook & Twitter will read just fine without thinking that parts of URL are really parts of their URL.

Answer (score 3):

You can encode the URL with urlencode(), then use urldecode() within your application to return the proper URL.